# Jquery - hide element after creating it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Function for creating elements:

```
function create_image(){
        <?php if(isset($avatar)) : ?>
            var brojac = 5;
        <?php else: ?>
            var brojac = 4;
        <?php endif; ?>
        var broj_slike = (5 - brojac) + 1,
        slike;
        for (var i = 0; i < brojac; i++) {
            slike += '<label for="image'+ broj_slike +'">Slika ' + broj_slike + '</label><input type="file" name="userfile" id="image' + broj_slike + '" />';
            broj_slike++;
        };
        return slike;
     }
```

Function that inserts elements on the page:

```
var code = $('#code'),
     id = $('input[name=id]').val(),
     url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>mali_oglasi/mgl_check_paid';
     code.on('focusout', function(){
        var code_value = $(this).val();
        if(code_value.length != 16 ) {
            if ($('p[role=code_msg]').length != 0 ) $('p[role=code_msg]').remove() ;
            code.after('<p role=code_msg>Pogrešan kod je unešen.</p>');
        } else {
            if ($('p[role=code_msg]').length != 0 ) $('p[role=code_msg]').remove() ;
            $.post(url, {id : id, code : code_value}, function(data){
                if($.trim(data) != 'TRUE'){
                    code.after('<p role=code_msg>Uneti kod je neispravan.</p>');
                } else {
                    /*This part here put elements on the page*/
                    code.after('<p role=code_msg>Status malog oglasa je promenjen.</p>')
                    .after(create_image()).hide();
                    code.prev().remove();
                    code.remove();
                }
        });
        }
     });
```

How can I hide new elements?

Comment: do these need to always be hidden or are they hidden for a period of time and will be shown later (e.g. show on button click or some similar method)?

Comment: I need it to be hidden so I can do slideDown animation.

Comment: why dont you pass style as display none with new element you are inserting.

Comment: Then I would apply a common class to all elements you are inserting and hide based on that class. So you have your element you are creating, wrap that in a container (<div> or something)... e.g. <div class='hideMe'>your content</div> and then you js would be $('hideMe').hide(); inserted at the end of your $.post callback function

Comment: @ntlarson That seems to the the trick. Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the entire code but hiding an element is as simple as using the hide method.

```
$('<div/>').appendTo('#el').hide();
```

I'm creating and inserting the element into the dom before hiding it - an example that should resemble yours, if I understood correctly. (it is a bad practice, though, to insert an element in the dom to hide it immediately afterwards - it'd be better to insert it in the dom already hidden - it'd prevent an unnecessary reflow).

Comment: You could hide it before appending. `$('<div/>').hide().appendTo('#el');` Or just `$('<div style="display:none;" />').appendTo('#el');`

Comment: `$('<div/>')`, exactly. It's one way to create elements with jquery http://jsfiddle.net/RgAtd/ - an advice for the future? Make sure you know what you're talking about before commenting as you did - otherwise you end up looking like idiots.

Comment: I think that either way is acceptable, but I personally prefer `$("<div>")`.

Comment: @Ark Go troll elsewhere. `<div>`, `<div></div>` and `<div/>` return the same match by jQuery core's regex pattern before handling single tag HTML. Go read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté i dont need to read any doc, the tag for div is <div> if the jquery accept it is because of people who dont know how to write html very well, the same way you dont need to close tags on html, but its wrong anyway.

Comment: @Ark `jQuery !== HTML`. Self-closing is a valid XML style and jQuery core has a module solely for handling that kind of writing. As I said, all 3 string examples above will trigger the same behavior - call a `document.createElement('div')` and wrap it inside a jQuery object. In fact, even the docs which I linked use `<div/>` in the description.

Comment: Ark, my friend... well not exactly my friend I suppose. This isn't html, it's jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 - dig a little deep on that page. After that go back to my previous comment - read it, let it sink. But hey, you do know how to close and open tags in html - that's pretty good stuff right there - you should be able to create some pretty awesome things packed with that knowledge.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté self-closing is a browser property, and jquery is not html but jquery is a library of js that uses html as base markup language. And yeah, you guys use ugly html...youre welcome

Comment: Writing a string that represents a single element !== HTML. Bleh never mind that.

Comment: @Ark It doesn't appear that way, but hey, I believe you.

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo:ya you are correct my friend.saw the docs.$("<div/>") is valid.

Answer (score 0):

With this: [`$(jqueryelement).hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

I would hide it before the element gets added to the DOM.

```
$('<div>').css({"display": "none"}).appendTo(elementInDOM);
```

OR

```
$(elementInDOM).append(
   $('<div>').css({"display": "none"})
);
```

I'm sure there are plenty of other ways!